# FluorineFx request as Externalized Object c#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, charles-proxy, fluorinefx

currently I am developing C# application that sends amf packet to server using FluorineFx.

It works fine, but I found out strange datatype called Externalized Object.

I found out that FluorineFX Contains a class named ArrayCollection but i dont now how i need to use it and the bigger problem, how i can send it as externalized object

This is the capture file from Charles and I have re-produce those Externalized Objects.

[pic](http://prnt.sc/aw48jx)

cheers, Niklas

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this but from **[this link](https://cvlib.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3/trunk/as3/com/coursevector/amf/AMF3.as)** you can learn that...

> A single AMF 3 type handles ActionScript Objects and custom user
>   classes. The term 'traits'  is used to describe the defining
>   characteristics of a class. In addition to `anonymous` objects  and
>   `typed` objects, **ActionScript 3.0 introduces two further traits to
>   describe how objects are  serialized, namely `dynamic` and
>   `externalizable`**.
>
> Anonymous : an instance of the actual ActionScript Object type or an
>   instance of a Class without  a registered alias (that will be treated
>   like an Object on deserialization)
>
> Typed : an instance of a Class with a registered alias
>
> Dynamic : an instance of a Class definition with the dynamic trait
>   declared; public variable members  can be added and removed from
>   instances dynamically at runtime
>
> **Externalizable** : an instance of a Class that implements
>   flash.utils.IExternalizable and completely  controls the serialization
>   of its members (no property names are included in the trait
>   information).

Between the above info, also this **[AS3 Docs entry](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/IExternalizable.html)** and this **[Fluorine Documentation](http://www.fluorinefx.com/docs/v17/as3customserialization.html)**, maybe it helps you get a direction on how to "re-produce those Externalized Objects".

PS: What happens if you just go ahead and treat Externalized object as normal Object? Your app/code may still work as expected.

Comment: my request needs to look like this http://prntscr.com/b0imyw
and it looks like this http://prntscr.com/b0in8o

and this doesnt works sadly